# are there any simple negation boolean operator in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean-expression, unary-operator

i want to make the boolean list to negated boolean list 
for example, below code has same meaning

```
lst= [True, False]
neg_lst = list(map(lambda x: not x, lst))
```

I think that there are the simplest way to make boolean list to be negated. 
like, unary operator. maybe.

always thanks for a lot of your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`not_`**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/operator.html#operator.not_) function from the `operator` package:

```
from operator import not_

map(not_, some_list)
```

Or you can use *list comprehension*:

```
[not x for x in some_list]
```

Comment: @frhyme: sure, therefore I don't see any reason why you subsequently failed to tag this with numpy :)